# How to setup 2 different solutions so that they can use a shared DTO / Messages assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

In writing my smart client application I currently have 2 separate solutions.

MyApp.BackEnd and MyApp.FrontEnd. Both solutions are under Subversion source control.

Currently, I have created a MyApp.Common assembly in the MyApp.BackEnd solution and I have added a reference to the DLL in the MyApp.FrontEnd solution. I don't really like this way of doing things but it works for now.

What I would like to do is somehow make it so that it is possible to keep the code files for MyApp.Common inside the MyApp.Backend solution but have the ability to create / edit them in the MyApp.FrontEnd solution.

This would give me the ability to hand off the MyApp.FrontEnd solution to a seperate developer and he / she will be able to define DTOs without the need to access the MyApp.Backend solution at all.

The problem is that I don't have any idea how to go about this. Please let me know if you need any more information. I know that it be potentially done by containing all the code files in one solution but that has the potential to be huge and I am quite keen on maintaining a separation between the backend and front end solutions.

Many thanks in advance for any assistance

**Solution:** With thanks to the answer from pjotr and this [helpful link](http://amadiere.com/blog/2009/06/multiple-subversion-projects-in-one-visual-studio-solution-using-svnexternals/) I have now managed to resolved this problem.

Simply, I used TortoiseSVN and in MyApp.FrontEnd repository chose ShowProperties then I added a property called svn-externals and pointed it to the DTO library in the MyApp.BackEnd repository from where I followed the instructions on the link. Now I'm away, thanks for all your help.

Comment: instead of adding DLL, why dont you add the project in to a common solution in visual studio and then reference the backend project in frontend and smart client project

Comment: Do you mean break out MyApp.Common project into a seperate solution and then reference this new solution from both MyApp.BackEnd and MyApp.FrontEnd?

Comment: No, have all the projects in the same solution and then reference the required project in MyApp.BackEnd, when you add reference to projects using visual studio you get an option for adding reference to project, use that

Comment: As I am using Prism and modules the problem with that approach is that I am likely to have a global solution that will have about 20 projects in and I just think it will get really slow...etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the existing library project to both solutions.

Either both solutions can live inside one repository, or you can have an svn:external to link the library project from one repository to another

Comment: Hi pjotr, I am not exactly sure what you mean. Do you mean I need to add the project (as in the class files) to both MyApp.FrontEnd and MyApp.BackEnd or something else? Thanks

Comment: Add the project MyApp.Common to MyApp.FrontEnd solution (in solution explorer, using Solution->Add existing project), then add reference to the project where necessary

Comment: Hi pjotr, if I do this I will be able to create the DTOs in the front end solution but only have a reference in the backend solution. I think what I am trying to achieve is the ability to create and edit the files in MyApp.Common from either the backend or frontend without having one massive solution that contains every project. It is important that I maintain the separation between backend and frontend solutions.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to tell - two solutions, solution-specific projects are only in one solution, common project(s) in both solutions. You already have MyApp.Common in BackEnd solution, now add it to FrontEnd solution as well.